# Go switch statements with additional booleans

Tags: go

Is it possible to have switch statements in go which allow for additional checks not based on the item being "switched over"? For example

```
myStr := "idk" // some string
code := getIntID(myStr) // will be an integer
isEven := (code % 2 == 0)

switch myStr {
   case "hello", isEven:
     return 5
   case "idk", !isEvent:
     return 12
   default:
     return 99
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can have this instead:

```
switch {
   case myStr=="hello", isEven:
   case myStr=="idk", !isEven:
}
```

Or:

```
switch {
   case myStr=="hello" && isEven:
   case myStr=="idk" && !isEven:
}
```

Comment: I somehow believe the OP wanted to have the conditions in the individual branches to be logically ANDed ;-)

Comment: @kostix, maybe. I added that as well.